# why same name of .ts and .d.ts its not working

Tags: typescript

My TypeScript version is 5.3.3.
When initializing a TypeScript project, I encountered the following error:

When using files with the same name, one with a `.ts` extension and the other with a `.d.ts` extension, in the same directory, referencing the types from the `.d.ts` file in the `.ts` file leads to a loss of type functionality.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}

// src/index.d.ts
interface Window {
  a: number
}


// src/index.ts
console.log('window.a :>> ', window.a) // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)
```

1. I attempted to rename `index.ts` and `index.d.ts` to `foo.ts` and `foo.d.ts`, but it didn't work.
2. Next, I tried renaming them to different names, like `index.ts` and `anotherindex.d.ts`, and this approach worked.
3. Next, Adding a triple-slash directive resolved the issue:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}

// src/index.d.ts
interface Window {
  a: number
}

// src/index.ts
/// <reference path="./x.d.ts" /> // add this
 
console.log('window.a :>> ', window.a) // its working
```

Can someone explain the underlying principles to me?

Comment: Why would you have a `.ts` and `.d.ts` together anyway? The idea is usually to have `.js` and `.d.ts`, because _you can't have types_ in `.js` and still have it be valid syntax, but you can in `.ts`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are correct. I wouldn't do this in a production environment. I just noticed this issue during local testing, and I'm puzzled by it.

Comment: [_"The resolution process always favors the `.ts` files over `.d.ts`."_](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10704#issuecomment-245336321)